# Basic select script takes a long time to retrieve 70 values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, select, execute

I have a gridview that has data-bound and template columns.    I won't paste the entire XML code here, but basically here is a breakdown of each column:

- Item ID (DataBound column)
- Item Category (DataBound Column)
- Item Sub-Category (DataBound Column)
- Item (DataBound Column)
- Order Qty (Textbox - unbounded template field)
- Supplier (DropDownList unbounded template field)**
- Item Cost (Textbox - unbounded template field)
- Paid (Checkbox - unbounded template field)

The gridview retrieves all records and filters only by the category selected (so only pulls through about 70 records per category - so its not HUGE).

In SSMS - this takes 0 seconds to execute.

In ASP.net takes about 20 seconds.

What makes it worse, the supplier DropDown is currently a blank field.  However, when I actually add this code to the source:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddSupplier" runat="server" DataSource="<%# PopulateControls() %>"  
                   DataTextField="SupplierName"  DataValueField="SupplierName" />
</ItemTemplate>
<ControlStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
<ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
           Width="50px" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

It then takes about 60 seconds to retrieve all values.

My Question:

1. Is there a faster way to pull values via basic select script in gridview?
2. Is there a problem with having 1 or more templates with bound fields?  I have other datagrids that contain ONLY data-bound columns and they execute quite quickly.

Help?

Comment: try to post your code-behind, it would help, probably you are doing another things that you are not aware of, by mistake or something, it should not take that long.

Comment: btw try to use the `RowDataBound` event for the DropDownList that you fill.. Execute the method just once... in the Page_Load or something, and save it in memory in ViewState or Session , and update it in the mentioned event, you are executing that function for each row, instead of just once

Comment: 60 seconds is probably database related, e.g. fetching all records and then filtering in memory. Please post the code behind, especially PopulateControls()?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code behind, I can only say this much. But there are already a few problems.

70 rows in a gridview is not small. Grids store a lot of data in ViewState. Paginate the data if possible. If not, try using the session for the ViewState.

The dataSource for `ddSupplier` will probably be the same. Set in on `RowDataBound`

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (gv.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex && 
       e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
   {       
       DropDownList ddSupplier= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddSupplier"); 
       //bind the control
       //MySuppliers would be read and kept in Session on first page load
       ddSupplier.DataSource = MySuppliers;
   }
}
```

The template bound fields are not a problem.

You could understand the problem better by profiling the code and see where those 20 secs are actually used.